# Rubycritic always returning 0 as error code on rake, but on console returns the error code fine according to minimum-score setting

Tags: ruby

```
desc 'runs RubyCritic with html output'
Rubycritic::RakeTask.new do |task|
  task.name = 'rubycritic'
  task.paths = FileList['**/*.rb'].exclude('**/*_spec.rb')
  task.options = '--minimum-score 95'
end
```

When I run on console, it works as intended, but using *rake*, the '`echo $?`' output is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on 'Rubycritic', it should be a capital C. i.e RubyCritic

This just shows that the code executed without an error as opposed to failing a test, it seems RubyCritic doesn't return a non 0 return code for it's rake task if it fails. One solution would be to call the bash command from rake:

```
desc 'runs RubyCritic with html output'
task :rubycritic do
  sh "rubycritic --minimum-score 95"
end
```